# How do I fix my VBA renaming program's 0 return?

Tags: vba, return-value, file-rename

I am open to completely changing this code. The link to the original is in the code itself. I'm sure there's an easier way to do it and the actual renaming part is NOT my own code, so I will redo it so it isn't plagiarizing. I can't use a batch file renamer to do it; I need to make it myself to stay out of trouble with legal :) No grey area!

Anyways, after a few dozen attempts on my own, I finally caved and grabbed this code online that is supposed to rename the files I specify. I edited it to fit my parameters and assigned variables/directories. When I run it, however, I always get a return of zero and the files are not being renamed. The one thing I could think of is that this directory is going to the full path name of the folder instead of the part after the last "\". But I'm not sure how to fix this either. I thought about trying to tell it to only tell it to pull, say the last 8 characters of the string, but that won't work either as these string lengths will vary anywhere from one character to 20 or so characters.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Apply_Click()
'This will initiate Module 1 to do a batch rename to find and replace all
'Module 1 will then initiate the resolving links process

Dim intResponse As Integer 'Alerts user to wait until renaming is complete
intResponse = MsgBox("Your folders are being updated. Please wait while your files are     renamed and your links are resolved.")

If intResponse = vbOK Then 'Tests to see if msgbox_click can start a new process
Dim i As Integer
Dim from_str As String
Dim to_str As String
Dim dir_path As String


from_str = Old_Name_Display.Text
to_str = New_Name.Text

dir_path = New_Name.Text
If Right$(dir_path, 1) <> "\" Then dir_path = dir_path _
    & "\"

Old_Name_Display = dir$(dir_path & "*.*", vbNormal)
Do While Len(Old_Name_Display) > 0
    ' Rename this file.
    New_Name = Replace$(Old_Name_Display, from_str, to_str)
    If New_Name <> Old_Name_Display Then
Name Old_Name_Display.Text As New_Name.Text
        i = i + 1
    End If

    ' Get the next file.
    Old_Name_Display = dir$()
Loop

MsgBox "Renamed " & Format$(i) & " files. Resolving links now."
If intResponse = vbOK Then
MsgBox "You selected okay. Good luck coding THIS." 'Filler line to test that next step     will be ready to initialize
Else: End
End If

Exit Sub


'Most of batch renaming process used from VB Helper, sponsored by Rocky Mountain Computer Consulting, Inc. Copyright 1997-2010; original code available at http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_rename_files.html


End Sub
```

Does anyone have another theory on why I get a 0 return/how to fix that potential above problem?

Comment: P.S. Ignore those module 1 comments. I decided to do it in the form itself since the Module was just causing me problems.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do? It's hard to tell just from looking at your code. This really shouldn't be tagged as batch-file because it's vba code. It certainly can be done in batch though. Edit your post and let us know what, specifically, you're trying to do and you'll get better answers.

Comment: Jimmy got it. What would you call it then for future reference? I'm doing the same thing as a batch file renamer would do...I'm finding files and renaming them in a group...sorry, guys. I'm a mechanical engineering student, not a programmer. I'm just doing a programming project at work.

Comment: You just need to read the description of the tag. batch-file is a tag for Windows Command Script related topics.

Comment: Updated...is that more accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the directory is getting referenced in the rename.

Change

```
Name Old_Name_Display.Text As New_Name.Text
```

to

```
Name Dir_Path & Old_Name_Display.Text As Dir_Path & New_Name.Text
```

Comment: No luck :( 

It still runs, but with the same result of 0. The Old_Name_Display does contain a full path as well. In this case (linking to my dummy project): U:\Common\AWeaver\Project Folder\10000

Comment: Can I set the directory path and then re-establish Old_Name_Display and New_Name as regular strings or will that mess it all up? I just started VB this weekend so I have no idea.

Comment: Yes you can.  Old_Name_Display I guarantee is losing the path.  Try to set a Watch on it in the debugger and step through the code with F8 and you'll get a better picture of what's going on.  Dir$() strips the path out of your string.

Comment: Oh I wondered what that did! Thanks, Jimmy! I got it. I added in a new box Path_Selected that pulled the directory path from Form1 and set that as the directory path! Thanks so much for your help!